# MouseListener of TrayIcon Position is not correct

Tags: java, swing, awt, system-tray

Is mouse position of trayicon of awt is correct consider a sample code,

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SampleTray extends MouseAdapter {
    private SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    private TrayIcon trayIcon;

    public SampleTray() {
        try {
            this.trayIcon = new TrayIcon(
                ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM3aS.png"))
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        this.trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        this.trayIcon.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        System.out.println("Screen Size is x " + screenSize.getWidth() + " y " + screenSize.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Mouse clicked at x " + e.getX() + " y " + e.getY());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SampleTray::new);
    }
}
```

Output of Above code:

```sh
Screen Size is x 1536.0 y 864.0
Mouse clicked at x 1638 y 1062
```

Why the x value is grater than the screen bounds ? My task bar is on bottom. How to get correct position relative to screen ?

Note : getXonScreen and getYonScreen return same and if the value is correct please explain me how this value is relative to screen from orgin (0 , 0).

Edit:

I am using this position to place the undecrotated window near that tray icon so i want this to be correct.

As @Gilbert Le Blanc Said problem is Scaling but when i change scale to 100% all are become too small and can't except that end-user is going to change the scaling for this software so what the way to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10?  Is screen scaling set to something greater than 100%?

Comment: Yeah! 125% which windows recomends to me and i tried Robot class in javafx(i am using javafx) it works perfect but this is not ?

Comment: But the problem with robot class is if user change mouse position immediately after click then it gives that position.

Comment: Swing was developed before there were high DPI displays.  Oracle has tried to fix the problem, but the "fixes" are worse than the problem, in my opinion.  This is the main reason I still use Java 8 to code Swing GUIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responce, It helped to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using the following idea,

```java
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    var scale = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution() / 96.0;
    System.out.println("Scaling Size is x " + scale );
    System.out.println("Size : " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    System.out.println("Mouse clicked at x " + e.getXOnScreen() / scale + " y " + e.getYOnScreen() / scale);
}
```

Note: This is not actual code that i used, i use javafx like

```java
var scaleX = Screen.getPrimary().getOutputScaleX();
var scaleY = Screen.getPrimary().getOutputScaleY();
```

But the idea is same, Hope this helps to feature readers.